# React JS add counting JSON elements

Tags: java, json, reactjs, count, datatables

everyone!
I using React and I would like output count "employees" from JSON like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA2vU.jpg)

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "departmentName": "Development",
    "employees": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Max",
            "departmentId": 1,
            "salary": 20000.0,
            "city": "berlin",
            "street": "First st.",
            "bankName": "bank",
            "cardNumber": "de12345678912"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Sam",
            "departmentId": 1,
            "salary": 20000.0,
            "city": "new york",
            "street": "Second st.",
            "bankName": null,
            "cardNumber": null
        }
    ]
},
```

For rendering JSON I'm using DataTable

```
<DataTable value={this.state.departments} paginator={true} rows="25" selectionMode="single"
                           selection={this.state.selectedDepartment}
                           onSelectionChange={e => this.setState({selectedDepartment: e.value})}>
                    <Column field="id" header="ID"/>
                    <Column field="departmentName" header="Department"/>
                </DataTable>
```

**How can I add a field for count employees?**

Comment: What datatable are you using, can you link to the npm package?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [this datatable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component#columns) (even though it doesn't have a Column field property) then you can give it a selector property:

```
<Column
  selector={(row) => row.employees.length}
  name="Employees"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In actual practice it's very easy

```
<Column field="employees.length" header="Employees"/>
```